# Error with updated Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

i have this code:

```
$.widget("custom.gamecomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            ul.append('<div id="searchItem_' + item.id + '" class="ico ico-' + item.platform + '"></div>');
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
        $(ul).children("li").each(function (index, li) {
            $(li).prepend($(ul).children("div.ico:first"));
        });
    }
});

// override close method - see link below for details
(function(){
    var originalCloseMethod = $input.data("gamecomplete").close();
    $input.data("gamecomplete").close = function(event) {
        if (!selected){
            //close requested by someone else, let it pass
            originalCloseMethod.apply( this, arguments );
        }
        selected = false;
    };
})();
```

And i receive this error

```
$input.data(...) is undefined
```

I think is because an update of Jquery Ui Autocomplete... how can i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is `$input` defined?

Comment: here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/975330baed3d8d79f08d

Comment: Did you solve that? And how?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and so I switched to typeahead.js (https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)